# How can get all objects whose sub object's property matches my string array using linq.js?

Tags: javascript, linq, linq.js

I have an array of tag names:

var tags =  ['tagOne', 'tagTwo']

Which I want to use, to query the array below and get all items which match a tag.

```
var items = 
[
{
  'name': 'itemOne',
  'tags': [
    { name: 'tagOne' }
  ]
},
{
  'name': 'itemTwo',
  'tags': [
    { name: 'tagTwo' }
  ]
}
];
```

How can I do this with linq Js? I.E in this case both items would be returned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this; it may not be the most efficient way (I've never used linq.js before) but it will work:

```
// Enumerate through the items
var matches = Enumerable.From(items)
    .Where(function(item) {
        // Enumerate through the item's tags
        return Enumerable.From(item.tags).Any(function(tag) {

            // Find matching tags by name
            return Enumerable.From(tags).Contains(tag.name);
        })
    })
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: Very, Very nice, very fresh. Thank you! Will give it a go tomorrow.

Comment: BTW you should checkout lodash (or underscore) - I love linq in the C# world but lodash is much more concise in the javascript world. Here's how you could do the same thing in lodash (apologies for formatting):  

var matches = _.filter(items, function(item) {
    return _.find(item.tags, function(itemTag) {
        return _.contains(tags, itemTag.name);
    })
});

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:-

Items

```
var items = 
[
{
  'name': 'itemOne',
  'tags': [
    { name: 'tagOne' }
  ]
},
{
  'name': 'itemTwo',
  'tags': [
    { name: 'tagTwo' }
  ]
},
{
  'name': 'itemThree',
  'tags': [
    { name: 'tagThree' }
  ]
}
];
```

Tags:-

```
var tags = ['tagOne', 'tagTwo'];
```

Search for Tags:-

```
var fillteredItems = items.filter(function(item){
    var tagsInItem = item["tags"];
    for (var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < tagsInItem.length; j++) {
            if(tags[i]==tagsInItem[j].name)
                return item;
        };
    };
});
```

Print Results:-

```
fillteredItems.forEach(function(item){
    console.log("items",item);
})
```

Comment: thank you, gave you an upvote. Yes I can do it using filter or using nested loops. I want to try to do with Linq.js though. I just think the solution will be a terser.